# Adding scale for node weight in network visualization

Tags: r, plot, visualization, igraph

I have created a network object `net` using igraph and plotted the visualization of this network below. I am trying to add a scale that correlates to the weight of the node. Would anyone know how I could modify my code to do so?

[image]

This is my code right now:

```
plot(net, layout = l, edge.curved = 0.25, vertex.size = V(net)$size*0.3, edge.width = E(net)$width*0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should direct `vertex.size` to your `weight` attribute in vertices (or any other numeric attribute that you want to play as the vertex size). For example, given a network `g` like below

```
n <- 5
g <- make_ring(n) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "weight", value = 10 * seq_along(V(.)))
```

where you have the vertex attribute `weight` (see the dummy values in `value =` ), and you can plot it by specifying  `vertex.size = V(.)$weight`, such that

```
g %>%
  plot(vertex.size = V(.)$weight)
```

and you will see

[image]